# adding items to listview in loop

Tags: c#, listview

I have a problem with listview. I am not sure how to use a loop to fill the items. The following code works for the first row and I think that I need to increment the row but I'm not sure how. When the list contains more than 1 entry I get the error message:

> Failed to compare two elements in the array

```
foreach (List<string> l in list)
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(l[0]);
    item.SubItems.Add(l[1]);
    item.SubItems.Add(l[2]);
    item.SubItems.Add(l[3]);
    item.SubItems.Add(l[4]);
    lstBooks.Items.Add(item);
}
```

below is the whole function. I originally had a problem with the list but it was solved here [populating a list of a list of strings but](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440684/populating-a-list-of-a-list-of-strings-but)

The view is set to details

```
    private void ListBooks()
    {
        lstBooks.Items.Clear();
        lstBooks.Columns.Clear();
        lstBooks.Visible = true;

        List<List<string>> list = db.ListDetailsByGenre();
        lstBooks.Columns.Add("Title", 120);
        lstBooks.Columns.Add("Author", 120);
        lstBooks.Columns.Add("Library", 120);
        lstBooks.Columns.Add("Genre", 120);



     foreach (List<string> l in list)

            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(l[0]);
            item.SubItems.Add(l[1]);
            item.SubItems.Add(l[2]);
            item.SubItems.Add(l[3]);
            item.SubItems.Add(l[4]);
            lstBooks.Items.Add(item);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     foreach (List<string> l in list)

        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(l[0]);
        item.SubItems.Add(l[1]);
        item.SubItems.Add(l[2]);
        item.SubItems.Add(l[3]);
        item.SubItems.Add(l[4]);
        lstBooks.Items.Add(item);

    }
```

You  are missing an { after your foreach (List l in list)  when you uploaded the larger portion of the code but not when you showed the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

I created the following test and no errors occurred.

```
        List<List<string>> list = new List<List<string>>();

        list.Add(new List<string> { "1a", "1b", "1c", "1d", "1e" });
        list.Add(new List<string> { "2a", "2b", "2c", "2d", "2e" });
        list.Add(new List<string> { "3a", "3b", "3c", "3d", "3e" });
        list.Add(new List<string> { "4a", "4b", "4c", "4d", "4e" });
        list.Add(new List<string> { "5a", "5b", "5c", "5d", "5e" });

        foreach (List<string> l in list)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(l[0]);
            item.SubItems.Add(l[1]);
            item.SubItems.Add(l[2]);
            item.SubItems.Add(l[3]);
            item.SubItems.Add(l[4]);
            lstBooks.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

Some points:

- The problem may be in the structure/data of `list` - provide an example of the contents of `list`.
- The `Add` method simply adds the ListViewItem to the end of the Items collection of the ListView, so you don't need to increment the row.
- It likely doesn't apply here, but you might want or need to clear the existing items from the ListView before populating it: `lstBooks.Items.Clear();`

What other listview properties might be changed from default, and at what point do you get the error?

Comment: His code looks good, what change did you make? its just that OP hasn't completed his question.

Comment: @Sanjee - The foreach loop is unchanged. I just populated `list` by creating a List of List<string> to test.

Comment: It gets cleared before reaching the loop. The first loop works perfectly but it crashes on the second. Have to go out for a while  out but will provide more code when I get back

Comment: Argghh I keep trying to add the full function but it keeps disappearing. What am I doing wrong??